# How to display multiple images in Cocoa for OSX?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

What I'm trying to achieve sounds pretty simple: regular simple window with a text field, view ,and a button.

In the field I'm placing the number (32 for example) and after I hit the button my view should be filled with 32 images. Don't really know how to accomplish this since I'm pretty new to Cocoa development.

So far I was just able to hardcode three NSViews and display 3 images at a time...which is not really what I want. So if anyone have any thoughts or hints I would totally appreciate it!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [IKImageBrowserView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/IKImageBrowserView/IKImageBrowserView_Reference.html).  Take a look at [ImageBrowser sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ImageBrowser/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003997). 
[image]

Comment: Thank you!This looks cool, hopefully I can adjust the code for my project!